# Split the data into three arrays based on the time

Tags: php, arrays, datetime, laravel

I want to split the data array into three arrays - past, today, later - based on the time.

For today's array, only data with today's date and the time greater than today's time should be there.

Here's my code. There is no bug in it (as far as I know). I am getting the desired result, but I want to know if this code can be more optimized.

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d');
$current_time = date('H:i:s');

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    if(date('Y-m-d', $value->meeting_scheduled_at) > $current_date) {
        $calendar_data['later'][] = $value;
    } elseif (date('Y-m-d', $value->meeting_scheduled_at) < $current_date
              || ( (date('Y-m-d', $value->meeting_scheduled_at) == $current_date) 
                   && (date('H:i:s', $value->meeting_scheduled_at) < $current_time) )
    ) {
        $calendar_data['past'][] = $value;
    } else {
        $calendar_data['now'][] = $value;
    }
}
```

`$value->meeting_scheduled_at` is in timestamp

EDIT: I am using this in a Laravel project.

So, if the meeting is scheduled at today's date, and time is evening 6 PM. It will come into today array till the 6 PM. After 6 PM, it goes into the past array. In short, nothing should be there in later array, unless and until it is next day.

Comment: Hope you got sorted. If you're happy with any of the answers provided, make sure you select your preferred answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use the `DateTime` class for this kinda thing. It takes into account daylight savings etc and can be compared really easily.

```
$now         = new DateTime();
$tomorrow    = new DateTime();
$meetingDate = new DateTime();

$tomorrow->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->setTime(0,0,0);

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $meetingDate->setTimestamp($value->meeting_scheduled_at);

    // if $value->meeting_scheduled_at format YYYY-MM-DD then
    // we'd create the $meetingDate object here like this
    // $meetingDate = new DateTime($value->meeting_scheduled_at);

    if ($meetingDate < $now) {
        $calendar_data['past'][] = $value;
    } else if ($meetingDate >= $tomorrow) {
        $calendar_data['later'][] = $value;
    } else {
        $calendar_data['now'][] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The variable `meeting_scheduled_at` stores date in timestamp. So, will it work with the timestamps?

Comment: @phantomphoenix You can either prefix with an `@` or use the `setTimestamp` method, I'll update my answer to reflect.

Comment: @phantomphoenix updated now, see that I've moved the initialisation of `$meetingDate` outside the `foreach` to conserve memory (only uses a single instance instead of 1 per meeting) and used just the `setTimestamp` method.

Comment: @phantomphoenix incidentally you can use `$meetingDate = new DateTime('@' . $value->meeting_scheduled_at);` to create it directly from a UNIX timestamp.

Comment: I am using Laravel and I get the following error upon running the code. `DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (1d)`.

Comment: @phantomphoenix Whoops, forgot the `P` in the format. Should've been `new DateInterval('P1D')`. Sorry, answer edited.

Comment: @phantomphoenix awesome, always nervous about writing stuff like this from memory... prefer to fire up a PHP console session to check it out (`php -a` from the terminal BTW :-)

Answer (score 2):

`date('Y-m-d', $value->meeting_scheduled_at)` should be calculated only once before you use its result in the conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Make it easier

```
$now = time();
// Midnight due to discussion with Kevin Nagurski in comments :) 
$tommorow = strtotime('tomorrow');
foreach($data as $key => $value) 
    if ($value->meeting_scheduled_at) < $now) $calendar_data['past'][] = $value;
    elseif ($value->meeting_scheduled_at) >= $tommorow) $calendar_data['later'][] = $value;
    else $calendar_data['now'][] = $value;
```

Comment: Your `$tommorow` doesn't take into account changes in daylight savings (and you spelled tomorrow incorrectly :-p)

Comment: @KevinNagurski about tomorrow = yes :) but I do not really understand the problem if we compare two taimstamps

Comment: Well, if the clocks go back an hour `strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $now)) + 60*60*24;` would equate to the same day at 11pm and if they went forward it would be the next day at 1am.

Comment: i hard understand about timezone and daylight but if strtotime(date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', $now)) is today, then +24 hours is  tomorrow, isn't it?. and changing time occurs at 2:00 :)

Comment: Yes, unless the date of the change is today, then 2am (1am some places) may or may not have already passed. For example, in the UK the next time change is on the 25th of October 2015, when the clocks will go back 1 hour, so `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2015-10-25 00:00:00') + (60*60*24));` = `2015-10-25 23:00:00`

Comment: perfectly! talked. but I understand correctly that 23:59:59 is always today ? :)

Comment: Yup, easiest way of getting that is either with the `DateTime` class or `strtotime('tomorrow') - 1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use timestamp instead.

```
$now = time();
$today_limt = strtotime("today 6 PM");

 foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $meeting_time = strtotime($value->meeting_scheduled_at);
        if($meeting_time > $today_limit) {
            $calendar_data['later'][] = $value;
        } elseif($meeting_time < $now) {
            $calendar_data['past'][] = $value;
        } else {
            $calendar_data['now'][] = $value;

        }
 }
```

Comment: Issue here would be that nothing will ever be classed as `now` and everything from today, even those that have passed will be classed as `later`.

Comment: How? `$today` means till 11:59:59 PM  today. So if any meeting time is greater than `$today` mid night, it should be later . `Noted:` I am not checking `LESS THAN` it is `GREATER THAN `

Comment: Actually, `$today = strtotime("today")-1;` evaluates to 23:59:59 yesterday. i.e. 2015-05-26 23:59:59 (my current date is 2015-05-27). Try it yourself: `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('today') -1);` I think you meant `tomorrow` not `today` in the `strtotime`

Comment: @KevinNagurski Sorry my mistake. I meant `Tomorrow-1` . Answer Updated. thanks

Comment: So, if the meeting is scheduled at today's date, and time is evening 6 PM. It will come into `today` array till the 6 PM. After 6 PM, it goes into the `past` array. In short, nothing should be there in `later array`, unless and until it is next day.